# Print year and exact date with biblatex chicago styles

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

Is there a way that I can specify some of the `biblatex-chicago` styles (either `biblatex-chicago` or `[style=chicago-authoryear]{biblatex}` so that they can make use of the `mergedate` feature? `authoryear-icomp` does this (with the code below), but I'd like to really use the Chicago styles.

I am trying to print lists of my publications, conference talks and media interviews and it really looks better for my purposes to have a bibliography (or publication lists) that print the year after the name followed by the exact date at the end.

Thank you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@unpublished{doc1,
title       = {my title},
author  = {My author},
journal     = {Journal of Me},
date = {2018-04-01}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp, mergedate=basic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\begin{document}


\cite{doc1}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`biblatex-chicago` is a very complex style, because it tries to implement the (no less) complex rules of the Chicago Manual of Style as closely as possible.

The code for the date handling alone is about 400 lines long. The following just transplants the code for `mergedate=basic` from `authoryear.cbx` into `biblatex-chicago`'s `authordate` style. I have not made any attempts to preserve the special handling of `date` and `origdate` or any of its date-related options from `biblatex-chicago`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{labeldate=year}

\renewbibmacro*{cmsbibsortdate}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{\printlabeldateextra}}}

\newbibmacro*{bbx:ifmergeddate}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iflabeldateisdate}
    and
    not test {\ifdateshavedifferentprecision{label}{}}
  }%
}

\renewbibmacro*{date}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:ifmergeddate}
    {}
    {\printdate}}%

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@unpublished{doc1,
  title   = {my title},
  author  = {My author},
  journal = {Journal of Me},
  date    = {2018-04-01}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{doc1}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: author, My. (2018). “my title.” April 1, 2018.]

Comment: Great. Can you explain what exactly the labeldate is? It might help me understand what is going on.

Comment: @spindoctor `labeldate` is the date that appears in the citation label. It is usually the same as `date` (and usually doesn't show more than the year). If `date` is not present `labeldate` may be calculated from other date fields (`urldate`, `origdate`, ...).